# Is the recent surge in bitcoin prices driven by Cypriot investors?

Tags: economics, europe, cyprus

There are [numerous stories](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&gl=uk&tbm=nws&q=bitcoin%20cyprus) out there linking the rise in bitcoin prices seen in the last few weeks with events in Cyprus.

[Some stories](http://betabeat.com/2013/04/the-cyprus-bitcoin-bubble-is-getting-ridiculous/) go as far as claiming that Cypriots are buying the things themselves as an "alternative store of value" e.g:

> Looking for a way to transfer their finances into something more
>   stable, Cypriots have flooded the Bitcoin market, dumping millions of
>   Euros into the fledgling online market.

Is there any actual concrete evidence that Cypriots (or I've also seen Greeks and Spaniards mentioned as buyers) are really doing this?  (All I can find is speculation apparently based on the timing of events).

Comment: Hoho.  After putting this up it's just been pointed out to me that bitcoin prices have just plummeted £174 to £70 in the last 8-9 hours or so.

Comment: Related to that country http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14006/could-obligatory-screening-for-thalassemia-in-cyprus-violate-the-bioethical-rule maybe we need a new tag?

Comment: @Carlo_R. Done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aha: In a [Der Spiegel article](http://www.spiegel.de/international/business/boom-of-digital-currency-bitcoin-raises-questions-of-stability-a-893342.html) I find

> Because the current boom began during the Cyprus crisis, there was
>   much speculation that it was primarily anxious Cypriots and Spaniards
>   who were using bitcoin as an inflation-proof, safe-haven currency. Jon
>   Matonis of the [Bitcoin Foundation](https://bitcoinfoundation.org/), which sees itself as an advocacy
>   group for fans of the alternative currency, disagrees. "Most
>   transactions are still coming from affluent regions, like the United
>   States and Northern Europe," he says. "What we are seeing is not a
>   Cyprus bubble."

And in fact Ars had this well covered [in an article a couple of weeks ago](http://arstechnica.com/business/2013/03/experts-pour-cold-water-on-claim-that-cyprus-crisis-caused-bitcoin-boom/) too which concludes:

> But there's still no hard evidence to suggest ordinary investors in
>   Spain, Russia, or anywhere else have been driving Bitcoin's recent
>   rise.